# difference between acting >= and > over a list

Tags: sql

```
SELECT name, area 
FROM world 
WHERE area > ALL (SELECT area FROM world 
                  WHERE continent="Europe" AND area IS NOT NULL)

SELECT name, area 
FROM world 
WHERE area >= ALL (SELECT area FROM world 
                   WHERE continent="Europe" AND area IS NOT NULL)
```

What is the difference between these 2 queries?

Because they both give different result.

Comment: You are asking what is the difference between 'greater than' and 'greater or equal than'.

Comment: [Math is fun](http://www.mathsisfun.com/equal-less-greater.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`2 >= 2` is true.
`2 >  2` is false.

your first query simply returns all countries in world that are bigger than all of countries in Europe (if you have set their area) in another word you are getting all countries that are bigger than the biggest country in Europe, the second query just returns all countries that are bigger than or equal to the biggest country in Europe.